# Add library to AndroidStudio project: Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, gradle, libraries

I got a project from a client which I'm supposed to fix. The developer of the app just bailed out and now it's up to me to fix it.

Problem is, that he probably developed with eclipse, while I'm using AndroidStudio. So it wasn't build with gradle. But I managed to import the project and fix it so far, that I can sync gradle.

But he seemed to use an external library, this one: https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders

I copied the content of the library folder into my project folder /libraries/tablefixheaders/.

I added `include 'libraries:tablefixheaders'` to my settings.grade and added `compile project('libraries:tablefixheaders')` to my dependencies in build.grade.

But if I want to rebuild the project now, I get `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`. Does the external library have to have a build.gradle? If so, how does it look like? I tried several things but nothing worked for me.

Comment: The way you integrated the other library, it needs to have a Gradle build. Alternatively, you can declare a dependency on the compiled library. See the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for how to do this.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working. I tried to migrate the library project to gradle, which won't work, and the User Guide doesn't really help me either :/

Comment: `dependencies { compile files("relative/path/to/aar") }`. Depending on your exact needs, you may also want to add a task that kicks off the (non-Gradle) build which produces that aar.

Comment: I managed to migrate the library as a gradle project. The only thing I was missing was the settings.gradle, I thought I'd only need that with multiple modules. But in this case I found out you create a settings.gradle in you root directoy with 'include ':'' and save it. This way I was able to migrate the library project to gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late :)

but I build a [wrapper for InqBarna's library](https://github.com/miguelbcr/TableFixHeaders-Wrapper) ready to use with gradle on this way:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.github.miguelbcr:TableFixHeaders-Wrapper:0.1.1"
}
```